# How to call a method having "context mContext"

Tags: java, android, parameters

I'm having trouble in calling this method:

```
public void loadArray(Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    WorkList.clear();
    int size = mSharedPreference1.getInt("Status_size", 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        WorkList.add(mSharedPreference1.getString("Status_" + i, null));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to load the saved data when start the application.
I tried to call `loadArray(MainActivity.this);` and got this:

```
> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
/Users/Long/AndroidStudioProjects/Hello/app/src/main/java/com/newthingtank/along/hello/MainActivity.java
Error:(33, 5) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(33, 24) error: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable type annotations)
Error:(33, 28) error: <identifier> expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.598 secs
Information:4 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: What's your "trouble"?

Comment: i dont know how to call it

Comment: You have to call `loadArray(YourActivity.this)` from your activity

Comment: i tried and got this:Error:(33, 5) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(33, 28) error: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable type annotations)
Error:(33, 32) error: <identifier> expected

Comment: You are currently using Java 7, but using Java 8 annotations. (As error describes). You should comment the whole error for more info.

Comment: i added the error on the question

Comment: I want to call this method in a non-activity class (the main class)